# Installing Oracle on M1 without VM?

Tags: sql, oracle, installation, oracle-sqldeveloper

Is there a way to install oracle 12c on MacOS? Because I am able to install SQL Developer, but I obviously can't use it if I can't install Oracle.

Btw I don't want to use a VM because of the low performance on the M1 and the ARM Architecture.

PS: I also have a windows PC. On this machine I installed Oracle and it works perfectly fine. If there is a way that I can connect to this "Server" please leave a stack overflow link below.

````
STATUS des LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for 64-bit Windows: Version 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Startdatum                25-DEZ-2020 23:09:33
Uptime                    0 Tage 1 Std. 29 Min. 12 Sek.
Traceebene               off
Sicherheit                ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Parameterdatei des Listener C:\Users\Ben\Desktop\db_home\network\admin\listener.ora
Logdatei des Listener    D:\benOracle\diag\tnslsnr\DESKTOP-FT8E4S1\listener\alert\log.xml
Zusammenfassung Listening-Endpunkte...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=1521)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(PIPENAME=\\.\pipe\EXTPROC1521ipc)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcps)(HOST=DESKTOP-FT8E4S1)(PORT=5500))(Security=(my_wallet_directory=D:\BENORACLE\admin\orcl\xdb_wallet))(Presentation=HTTP)(Session=RAW))
Services ▄bersicht...
Dienst "52448234712340b69f274bcc790ecfe0" hat 1 Instanzen.
  Instanz "orcl", Status READY, hat 1 Handler f³r diesen Dienst...
Dienst "CLRExtProc" hat 1 Instanzen.
  Instanz "CLRExtProc", Status UNKNOWN, hat 1 Handler f³r diesen Dienst...
Dienst "cfc353defce0494a8a440e7d1f817c2d" hat 1 Instanzen.
  Instanz "orcl", Status READY, hat 1 Handler f³r diesen Dienst...
Dienst "orcl" hat 1 Instanzen.
  Instanz "orcl", Status READY, hat 1 Handler f³r diesen Dienst...
Dienst "orclXDB" hat 1 Instanzen.
  Instanz "orcl", Status READY, hat 1 Handler f³r diesen Dienst...
Dienst "orclpdb" hat 1 Instanzen.
  Instanz "orcl", Status READY, hat 1 Handler f³r diesen Dienst...
Der Befehl wurde erfolgreich ausgef³hrt.
LSNRCTL>```
````

Comment: Were you able to run it on M1? I am still struggling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apologies for the wall of text in advance.

**1.Section for the windows installation. See section-2 below for docker setup**
(Assuming relative paths to DB_HOME which is generally under $INSTALL_DIRECTORY\product$RELEASE_VERSION$DB_HOME_NAME, ie D:\Oracle\DB\12201\i0\product\12.2.0\dbhome_1 where `INSTALL_DIRECTORY=D:\Oracle\DB\12201\i0`, `RELEASE_VERSION=12.2.0`, `DB_HOME_NAME=dbhome_1`) You need to be checking your listener.ora and tnsnames.ora file under `$DB_HOME\network\admin\listener.ora` and `$DB_HOME\network\admin\tnsnames.ora` (The latter is for having a alias for any native ojdbc client but it is good checksum to do testing with the tnsping etc.)

With 12c desktop-type installation, you get two listener definitions.

For the listener and tnsnames files, one-key point is to have the address of the machine setup properly. Unless you have the luxury of a static-ip, it is better have hostname based definitions which you can setup and switch around through your hosts file (C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts, if you are opening with notepad) such as:

```
127.0.0.1   MY-AWESOME-MACHINE
```

where the $HOSTNAME in the following files will be "MY-AWESOME-MACHINE". Obviously, this is an alias for your ipv4 loopback address but you can set it up to be what is available to your Mac host for your VM's IP Address. So the IP address can change but you can just update the assignment your hosts file and restart your tns-listener service (OracleOraDB1Home1TNSListener if you did not temper with it).
As a rule of thumb, I try to keep my custom hostname definitin aligned with the Windows physical or virtual machine's "Device Name" which can be set in Settings/System/About -> "Rename this PC"

See the following.

**listener.ora** should have:

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = **$DB_HOME**)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
      (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:**$DB_HOME**\bin\oraclr12.dll")
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = **$HOSTNAME**)(PORT = 1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
  )
```

**tnsnames.ora** should preferably have:

```
ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = CLRExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )

LOCALORCLPDB=
  (DESCRIPTION=
    (ADDRESS=
      (PROTOCOL=TCP)
      (HOST=**$HOSTNAME**)
      (PORT=1521)
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA=
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = ORCLPDB)
    )
  )
```

**2.Docker-based Container setup**
For a docker-based (18.06-ce) installation on setup on an EL7/EL7 machine, I use the following for my setup. I never had the chance to try it with M1 or let alone an ARM-ISA based machine but if it can help you, I am leaving it below.

In order to obtain the image (container-registry.oracle.com/database/enterprise:12.2.0.1-slim) you need to sign-up to oracle container registry which requires an oracle account (You can create a free one) with which you access the website for the following:
Login-to: https://container-registry.oracle.com
Go-to: Browse Containers/Database
@Database-Repositries-Page: Select Language, click "continue" in right-most column for "enterprise" repository. Agree to the prompt for development-only use.
@Database-Repositries-Page: Click the "enterprise" under "repository" column.
@Oracle-Database-Enterprise-Edition: Down below in the tags portion you can see the available images
In-your-command-line-running-docker-engine(1): execute "docker login container-registry.oracle.com"
In-your-command-line-running-docker-engine(2): you will be prompted for your oracle account username (e-mail) and password. paste-enter in order.
Pull-the-image: docker pull container-registry.oracle.com/database/enterprise:12.2.0.1-slim

## Create the configuration file directory

```
mkdir $HOME/dkr-oradb-ecfg
```

## Create Docker Volume directories

```
mkdir -p $HOME/shared/DockerVolumes/ORA-DB/DB-ORA-SLIM-0

# Create the credential file, it might not be able to override values so this rather more for reference, DO NOT USE in PRODUCTION especially for an instance with public access
sh -c 'cat << EOF > $HOME/dkr-oradb-ecfg/db-ora-slim-0.env.list
ORACLE_SID=orclcdb
ORACLE_PDB=orclpdb1
ORACLE_PWD=Oradoc_db1
EOF'

# Run the container
# As a rule-of-thumb I try to forward the ports exposed from a container as much as I can, so you can opt to run with the defaults. The catch is, the forwarded ports should be allowed in via firewall (in case a firewall is present)
docker run -d --name db-ora-slim-0 -p 32200:1521 -p 32201:5500 -v $HOME/shared/DockerVolumes/ORA-DB/DB-ORA-SLIM-0:/opt/oracle/oradata --env-file $HOME/dkr-oradb-ecfg/db-ora-slim-0.env.list container-registry.oracle.com/database/enterprise:12.2.0.1-slim
```

You should be able to connect to the CDB with SID (ip-address:32200:orclcdb) or PDB(ip-address:32200/orclpdb1) with service name.

Answer (score 4):

No, we don't have a native OS X database solution.

Your options:

1. Docker, Oracle Linux
2. VirtualBox, Oracle Linux
3. Oracle Cloud, Always Free Autonomous Database

If you don't want a VM, then option 3 is fairly straightforward.

[Here's everything you'd need to know from a respected expert and blogger from the community.](https://dgielis.blogspot.com/2019/09/best-and-cheapest-oracle-apex-hosting.html?m=1)

If your windows and Mac are on the same network...can you ping your windows machine from the Mac? If so, then yes you could connect. You just need a listener configured properly on the windows box, alongside your database.

Comment: First of all, thank you for the response. "You just need a listener configured properly on the windows box, alongside your database.", do know you were I can find information about this on how to do it (?), are these also on your linked website ? Btw I am able to ping my PC...

Comment: Then try this, basic connection in sqldeveloper with the IP address of your windows machine, port 1521, and service name of your database (don't use SID)

Comment: What is the service name or where can I find it ? Sorry, but im quite new to oracle

Comment: On your windows box, run from cmd prompt, lsnrctl status, then append that output to your question

Comment: Regarding the VM approach, I've used this for years on my Mac and performance is fine (I don't use it for any real work though, it's just a sandbox for playing around with stuff.) Using the Windows PC as a server sounds good too, though.

Comment: Yes, I use option 2 on my Mac Mini, runs just fine

Comment: After a bit troubleshooting  if found out, that I am not able to ping my PC. I used to ping my standartgateway, but not my actually IP-Adress. If I try to ping the ip-address in the Terminal I receive a instant timeout with 100% package lost. What could be the error in this case? I also tried the following query on sql*plus on my windows machine: SELECT UTL_INADDR.get_host_address from dual;. But the output was an ipv6 wich I could not enter in sql developer.

Comment: If I try to connect with "10.0.0.10" as the IP-Address I at least get the window that indicates, that it try's to connect to smth. But after 1-2 minutes it just throws an error again.

Comment: Gotta fix your networking setup first, and that's not pertinent to this question...

Comment: Ok, but why am I not able to connect via ipv6 ? this should work also

Comment: Get your ip4 address

Comment: Set up some firewall settings and now im am able to ping to my machine, but still not able to connect to my sql server on the windows machine - I used ipv4

Comment: Sql server? I'm here to help you with oracle

Comment: I ment Oracle Sql. I don't know why I can't connect. Port is correct 1521, used ipv4 and username and password for the connection also correct. I do get the loading sign, but it can't connect.

Comment: I've tried changing up the tns name file in order to fit my needs, but it still won't work. Also restored the database and the pc.  This is the error, it gets thrown after 1,5 minutes of trying to connect to the db: "Bei der Ausführung des angeforderten Vorgangs ist ein Fehler aufgetreten:

I/O-Fehler: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection

Herstellercode 17002" Dont hesitate if you need more information.

Comment: We asked you to record the output of running the listener command... remember?

Comment: I do remember. There were several. I tried all of them.                                             When I run the common lsnrctl status command, there are lots of infos. Is (HOST = LOCALHOST) correct, or should this be an IP address ?

Comment: Like I said, update your question with the output